# Why is this XML DOM Parser Not Parsing the rtept, name, and cmt tags correctly?

Tags: java, android, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I'm totally stumped on this DOM XML Parser at the moment. I'm getting the wrong info for two of the tags and I can't figure out why those two tags (name and cmt) keep having the same info instead of the correct info.

The XML I'm using is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd" version="1.1" creator="http://ridewithgps.com/">
  <metadata>
    <name>Home Test</name>
    <link href="http://ridewithgps.com/routes/1714475">
      <text>Home Test</text>
    </link>
    <time>2012-09-13T16:08:10Z</time>
  </metadata>
  <rte>
    <name>Home Test</name>
    <rtept lat="39.41333" lon="-77.4624">
      <name>Right</name>
      <cmt>Turn right onto Grouse Dr</cmt>
    </rtept>
    <rtept lat="39.41288" lon="-77.46297000000004">
      <name>Right</name>
      <cmt>Turn right onto Hunting Horn Ln</cmt>
    </rtept>
    <rtept lat="39.41431" lon="-77.46625">
      <name>Right</name>
      <cmt>Turn right onto Partridge Way</cmt>
    </rtept>
    <rtept lat="39.41431" lon="-77.46625">
      <name>Left</name>
      <cmt>Turn left onto Hunting Horn Ln</cmt>
    </rtept>
    <rtept lat="39.41288" lon="-77.46297000000004">
      <name>Left</name>
      <cmt>Turn left onto Grouse Dr</cmt>
    </rtept>
    <rtept lat="39.41333" lon="-77.4624">
      <name>Right</name>
      <cmt>Turn right onto Grouse Ct</cmt>
    </rtept>
  </rte>
</gpx>
```

The XML Parser I put together is as follows:

```
        public void parseXMLFile(String fullpath) {
        String metadata_name = null;
        String metadata_link_href = null;
        String metadata_link_name = null;
        String metadata_time = null;
        String rte_name = null;
        Double point_lat = null;
        Double point_lon = null;
        Double last_lat = null;
        Double last_lon = null;
        String point_name = null;
        String point_cmt = null;
        Float distance_to = null;

        // File f = new File(fullpath);
        String fileContents = null;
        try {
            fileContents = readFileAsString(fullpath);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            Document doc = (Document) loadXMLFromString(fileContents);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
            Log.d("XML", "ROOTNODE:" + root.getNodeName());

            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("metadata");

            Node nodee = nodeList.item(0);
            Log.d("XML", "NODELISTLENGTH1:" + 
                    nodee.getChildNodes().getLength());

            for (int i = 0; i < nodee.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nodee.getChildNodes().item(i);
                if (node.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
                    metadata_name = node.getTextContent();

                } else if (node.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                    NamedNodeMap attributes = node.getAttributes();
                    if (attributes.getNamedItem("href") != null) {
                        String href = attributes.getNamedItem("href")
                                .getNodeValue();
                        metadata_link_href = href;

                    }
                    metadata_link_name = node.getTextContent();
                    // Log.i("XML", "link node:" + node.getTextContent());
                } else if (node.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("time")) {

                    metadata_time = node.getTextContent();
                }

            }

            // DO THE RTE NODES AFTER THIS
            NodeList nodeList2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("rte");

            Node nodee2 = nodeList2.item(0);
            Log.d("XML", "NODELISTLENGTH2:"
                    + nodee2.getChildNodes().getLength());

            for (int i = 0; i < nodee2.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nodee2.getChildNodes().item(i);

                if (node.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {

                    rte_name = node.getTextContent();

                } else if (node.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("rtept")) {

                    NamedNodeMap attributes = node.getAttributes();
                    if (attributes.getNamedItem("lat") != null) {
                        // STORE THE LAST LAT FOR MEASURING DISTANCE BETWEEN
                        if (point_lat != null) {
                            last_lat = point_lat;
                        }
                        point_lat = Double.parseDouble(attributes.getNamedItem(
                                "lat").getNodeValue());

                    }
                    if (attributes.getNamedItem("lon") != null) {
                        // STORE THE LAST LON FOR MEASURING DISTANCE BETWEEN
                        if (point_lon != null) {
                            last_lon = point_lon;
                        }
                        point_lon = Double.parseDouble(attributes.getNamedItem(
                                "lon").getNodeValue());

                    }
                    NodeList rteptList = doc.getElementsByTagName("rtept");
//                  NodeList rteptList = node.getChildNodes();


                    Node nodee3 = rteptList.item(0);
                    Log.d("XML", "NODELISTLENGTH3:"
                            + nodee3.getChildNodes().getLength());
                    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < nodee3.getChildNodes().getLength(); i1++) {
                        Node rteptNode = nodee3.getChildNodes().item(i1);
                        if (rteptNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {

                            point_name = rteptNode.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

                        } else if (rteptNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("cmt")) {

                            point_cmt = rteptNode.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

                        }

                    }
                    // DO THE DATABASE STORAGE HERE
                    Log.i("XML", "name node:" + metadata_name);
                    Log.i("XML", "link node:" + metadata_link_name);
                    Log.i("XML", "link attribute [href]:" + metadata_link_href);
                    Log.i("XML", "time node:" + metadata_time);
                    Log.i("XML", "rte_name:" + rte_name);
                    Log.i("XML", "point_lat:" + point_lat.toString());
                    Log.i("XML", "point_lon:" + point_lon.toString());
                    Log.i("XML", "point_name:" + point_name);
                    Log.i("XML", "point_cmt:" + point_cmt);
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String estr = e.getStackTrace().toString();
            Log.d("XML", "XML Exception: " + e + ":" + estr);
        }
    }
```

`

I'm seeing output that is wrong...

```
09-15 03:37:20.963: D/XML(14951): NODELISTLENGTH3:5
09-15 03:37:20.963: I/XML(14951): name node:Home Test
09-15 03:37:20.963: I/XML(14951): link node:      Home Test    
09-15 03:37:20.963: I/XML(14951): link attribute [href]:http://ridewithgps.com/routes/1714475
09-15 03:37:20.963: I/XML(14951): time node:2012-09-13T16:08:10Z
09-15 03:37:20.963: I/XML(14951): rte_name:Home Test
09-15 03:37:20.963: I/XML(14951): point_lat:39.41288
09-15 03:37:20.963: I/XML(14951): point_lon:-77.46297000000004
09-15 03:37:20.963: I/XML(14951): point_name:Right
09-15 03:37:20.963: I/XML(14951): point_cmt:Turn right onto Grouse Dr
09-15 03:37:20.973: D/XML(14951): NODELISTLENGTH3:5
09-15 03:37:20.973: I/XML(14951): name node:Home Test
09-15 03:37:20.973: I/XML(14951): link node:      Home Test    
09-15 03:37:20.973: I/XML(14951): link attribute [href]:http://ridewithgps.com/routes/1714475
09-15 03:37:20.973: I/XML(14951): time node:2012-09-13T16:08:10Z
09-15 03:37:20.973: I/XML(14951): rte_name:Home Test
09-15 03:37:20.973: I/XML(14951): point_lat:39.41333
09-15 03:37:20.973: I/XML(14951): point_lon:-77.4624
09-15 03:37:20.973: I/XML(14951): point_name:Right
09-15 03:37:20.973: I/XML(14951): point_cmt:Turn right onto Grouse Dr
```

Why is point_name ALWAYS "Right" and point_cmt ALWAYS "Turn right onto Grouse Dr"?
How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use JOOX to get it done because the code is easier and simpler to understand...

```
public void parseXMLFile(String fullpath) {
    String metadata_name = null;
    String metadata_link_href = null;
    String metadata_link_name = null;
    String metadata_time = null;
    String point_lat = null;
    String point_lon = null;
    String last_lat = null;
    String last_lon = null;
    String point_name = null;
    String point_cmt = null;
    String fileContents = null;

    try {
        fileContents = readFileAsString(fullpath);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        Document doc = (Document) loadXMLFromString(fileContents);

        for (Match metadata : $(doc).find("metadata").each()) {
            Match c = metadata.children();
            for (int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++) {
                metadata_name = c.find("name").text();
                metadata_link_href = c.find("link").attr("href").toString();
                metadata_link_name = c.find("link").find("text").text();
                metadata_time = c.find("time").text();
            }
        }

        for (Match rte2 : $(doc).xpath("//rte").andSelf().each()) {
            rte2.children();
            for(Match rtetag : rte2.children().each()) {
                if(rtetag.tag().equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
                    rtetag.text();
                }
                if(rtetag.tag().equalsIgnoreCase("rtept")) {
                    for(Match rtepttag : rtetag.children().andSelf().each()) {
                        if(rtepttag.tag().equals("name")) {
                            point_name = rtepttag.text();
                        }
                        if(rtepttag.tag().equals("cmt")) {
                            point_cmt = rtepttag.text();
                        }
                        if(rtepttag.tag().equals("rtept")) {
                            if(last_lon == null) {
                                last_lon = point_lon;
                            }
                            if(last_lat == null) {
                                last_lat = point_lat;
                            }
                            point_lat = rtepttag.attr("lat");
                            point_lon = rtepttag.attr("lon");

                            //done parsing? here's some log stuff to check
                             Log.d("XML", "META_NAME:" + metadata_name);
                             Log.d("XML", "META_LINK_HREF:" + metadata_link_href);
                             Log.d("XML", "META_LINK_NAME:" + metadata_link_name);
                             Log.d("XML", "META_TIME:" + metadata_time);
                             Log.d("XML", "POINT_NAME:" + point_name);
                             Log.d("XML","POINT_CMT:"+point_cmt);
                             Log.d("XML", "POINT_LAT:" + point_lat);
                             Log.d("XML", "POINT_LON:" + point_lon);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        String estr = e.getStackTrace().toString();
        Log.d("XML", "XML Exception: " + e + ":" + estr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to replace below snippet in your code.

```
 Node nodee3 = rteptList.item(0);
                    Log.d("XML", "NODELISTLENGTH3:"
                            + nodee3.getChildNodes().getLength());
                    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < nodee3.getChildNodes().getLength(); i1++) {
                        Node rteptNode = nodee3.getChildNodes().item(i1);
                        if (rteptNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {

                            point_name = rteptNodenode.getTextContent();

                        } else if (rteptNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("cmt")) {

                            point_cmt = rteptNodenode.getTextContent();

                        }

                    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Did you mean for "rteptNodenode" to be "rteptNode"? Otherwise "rteptNodenode" is undefined.

When I fix it and run it, the results are still the same... the values displayed to point_name and point_cmt never change.

Comment: Here's the results (snipped) with your changes:
`09-15 08:24:19.793: I/XML(15085): point_name:Right
09-15 08:24:19.793: I/XML(15085): point_cmt:Turn right onto Grouse Dr
...
09-15 08:24:19.793: I/XML(15085): point_name:Right
09-15 08:24:19.793: I/XML(15085): point_cmt:Turn right onto Grouse Dr
...
09-15 08:24:19.803: I/XML(15085): point_name:Right
09-15 08:24:19.803: I/XML(15085): point_cmt:Turn right onto Grouse Dr
...
09-15 08:24:19.803: I/XML(15085): point_name:Right
09-15 08:24:19.803: I/XML(15085): point_cmt:Turn right onto Grouse Dr
`

Comment: i have change the line "point_name = rteptNodenode.getTextContent();" please try to add this.

Comment: okay.. but then it wont compile with an undefined error. I'll try it and see if maybe I need to clear the lint for it. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

In your code I see

```
NodeList rteptList = doc.getElementsByTagName("rtept");
// NodeList rteptList = node.getChildNodes();

Node nodee3 = rteptList.item(0);
```

Your current code is only getting the first "rtept" node and getting the "name" and "cmt", so only values from the first node are being used.

The commented out line was on the right track.  You need to get the child nodes from the current node and find the "rtept" node within them.